# R: return an object, which contains a variable

Tags: r

Based on calculations I have created **a list**, which contains 10 lists named by year (e.g. y2000 for 2000) and each year-list contains, in its turn, two result matrices (A and B).

For analysis purpose I would like to create a variable year and matrix, assign values to them.
For instance: `year = 2000` and `matrix = A`
Based on this variables I would like to return a desired matrix.

I tried to use `get()` with `paste0()` and different ways of list-notation, however none of the tries returned the result.

If I run
`Data$y2000$A` - the matrix is being returned, but

```
get(paste0("Data[[y",year,"]][[",matrix,"]]))
```

returns an error

> *object 'y2000' not found*

also I have tried to use brackets and backticks, but it still returns the same error.

```
get(paste0("Data[[`y",year,"`]][[`",matrix,"`]]))
```

How one can return an object via a variable?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It's best to avoid `get()` and `assign()` especially considering you can't use them with functions like `[[]]` and `$` in the variable "names".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need `get` here.  Instead extract the elements dynamically by creating the element names of 'Data' with `paste`

```
Data[[paste0('y', year)]][[matrix]]
```

Comment: As usual, the solution was simpler! Thank you a lot!